# checking for collision of a rotated shape in p5.js

Tags: javascript, rotation, processing, collision-detection, p5.js

I am trying to recreate the game [duet](https://www.duetgame.com/) but I can't figure out how to check collision on an that has been translated and rotated.

To rotate my players blue and red ball I translated the object to the center of the screen and then rotated it based on that point.

here is my [code](https://editor.p5js.org/Grant.Miller/sketches/kHbmjOq0x) (I know its not the best code, this is just a prototype)

how can I check for collision with the white obstacles and the players circles?

What exactly happens to the X and Y coordinates when you translate/rotate the shape?

Comment: You must add the code in the question. Links to external resources tend to break or the content may change. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.**"*. See also [Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could use matter.js  which already includes a collision detector engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind your polygon hit testing being based on a single point then it is fairly trivial. You can implement the [point in polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) algorithm which basically consists of counting intersections between a horizontal line and the edges of the polygon.

```js
const pts = []

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  pts.push(
    createVector(56, 89), createVector(108, 37), createVector(117, 118) 
  )
}

function draw() {
  background('#fff29c');

  if (pts.length > 1) {
    stroke('#301551');
    fill(pointInPoly(pts, createVector(mouseX, mouseY)) ? 'white' : 'grey');
    beginShape();
    pts.forEach(pt => vertex(pt.x, pt.y));
    endShape(CLOSE);
  } else if (pts.length == 1) {
    stroke('#301551');
    beginShape();
    pts.forEach(pt => vertex(pt.x, pt.y));
    vertex(mouseX, mouseY);
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
  
  stroke('white');
  line(0, mouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
  noStroke();
  intersections.sort((v1, v2) => v1.x < v2.x ? -1 : (v1.x > v2.x ? 1 : 0))
  for (let i = 0; i < intersections.length; i++) {
    fill(i % 2 == 0 ? 'green': 'red');
    circle(intersections[i].x, intersections[i].y, 5);
  }

  fill('#ed8a0a');
  noStroke();
  circle(mouseX, mouseY, 10);
}

let intersections = [];

function pointInPoly(verts, pt) {
  intersections = [];
  let c = false;
  // for each edge of the polygon
  for (let i = 0, j = verts.length - 1; i < verts.length; j = i++) {
    // Compute the slope of the edge
    let slope = (verts[j].y - verts[i].y) / (verts[j].x - verts[i].x);
    
    // If the mouse is positioned within the vertical bounds of the edge
    if (((verts[i].y > pt.y) != (verts[j].y > pt.y)) &&
        // And it is far enough to the right that a horizontal line from the
        // left edge of the screen to the mouse would cross the edge
        (pt.x > (pt.y - verts[i].y) / slope + verts[i].x)) {
      
      // To help visualize the algorithm.
      intersections.push({ x: (pt.y - verts[i].y) / slope + verts[i].x, y: mouseY });
      // Flip the flag
      c = !c;
    }
  }
  return c;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.4.1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
```

If you want your hit testing to be based on a circle you could also perform collision detection between the circle and each polygon edge segment in addition to the point-in-polygon algorithm.

Here is a description of how to do this from [a tutorial I wrote](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1174676) on detecting calculating circle collisions:

> Given a line defined by two points on that line (p1 and p2), let the boundaryVector be a vector from the first point to the second. We will assume that the vector produced by rotating boundaryVector clockwise 90 degrees orients it towards the inside of the bounded area. In other words the points must be specified in a clockwise order around the boundary.

> Given boundaryVector we can find the distance of the center of a circular body, give by pos, to the nearest point on the line, by taking the distance from p1 to pos, and multiplying it by the sine of the angle between boundaryVector and the vector from p1 to pos.

[image: a diagram of the mathematical components for calculating the distance between the center of a circle and a boundary vector]

> If the distance from the center of the circular body to the nearest point on the line is less than or equal to the radius of the circle, then a collision has occurred.

This assumes that the boundary is infinite, but you should be able to adopt this technique to properly handle finite line segments.